# Why does Portage complain for lack of a `portage` Python module?

Tags: gentoo, portage

I'm currently trying to get a Gentoo Prefix set up. I grabbed the bootstrap script and ran it, and it got partway through stage three and finished installing the kernel headers before Portage broke. It looks like the script went on to try to install some more packages, but any attempt to invoke `emerge` just result in an `ImportError`:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "$EPREFIX/usr/bin/emerge", line 41, in <module>
>     import portage
> ImportError: No module named 'portage'
> ```

Oddly enough, there *is,* in fact, a directory at `$EPREFIX/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/portage`, complete with `__init__.py` and at least a couple dozen modules. And invoking the prefixed `python2` directly with `-c 'import portage'` works just fine (trying that with the host system's Python gives that `ImportError`). As far as I can tell, though, things should be using the prefixed Python; the prefixed `bin`s are at the front of `$PATH`. Perhaps something in the script's internals is mistakenly resetting or ignoring `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your `python`! It might not be the version you expect. On my system, `python` was symlinked to `python3.5`, even though `sys-apps/portage` (which provides the `portage` Python package) didn't yet have a target for Python 3.5. Argh!

At this point, you won't be able to rebuild `portage` with different targets (because `emerge` is broken), so check all of the installed Python versions (or dig around in `$EPREFIX/usr/lib/python*/site-packages`) until you find one with a `portage` package. If you have a working `eselect` (I did), you can use it (see `eselect python help`); else, you can *probably* get away with just manually changing the symlink. Portage worked fine for me after this.

---

As for the Prefix bootstrap…it seems that if you just run the script interactively again, it'll start allll over again, right from the beginning. I didn't want to start over, so I switched to the [“manual” bootstrapping process](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix/Manual_Bootstrap) and picked up at stage three, where the script had failed. I'm really not sure why this method is recommended against, given that the bootstrapping script does all the work, just like in the recommended method.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same probelem druing crosscompilation of an arm based system - armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi. The problem started after I uptedated portage eix and portage-utiles. next time chrooting and env-update or emerge the process faild with the exact message posted above.

I thought, it must be related to the executrion of the python script and emerged python-exec from the host environment - emerge went fine, however did not solve the problem. I staterd looking around in the lib directories and realzed that due to the crosse-dev environment I got a lib64 in /usr and in there a portage directroy. I merged them with /usr/lib and made asymlink from /usr/lib -> /usr/lib64. the same under /. the problem dscribed is gone for me.

I dont know if this will apply for your case too, but it might give you a new hint which direction to search ;)

cheers !

Comment: correction, a /usr/lib/python2.7 and /usr/lib/python3.4 directory under /usr/lib/64...

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted, but I had a similar issue setting up a crossdev-backed musl toolchain.